# Exponential (?) solution to non-autonomous "infinite-dimensional" linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $V$ be a "nice" real Banach space, $T > 0$, $A : [0,T] \to V$ and $B : [0,T]\to \mathcal L(V,V)$ a family of bounded linear operators, such that $B_t$ commute with $v\mapsto \int_0^t B_s(v)\,ds$ for all $t\geq 0$. Further, we assume $A$ and $B$ to be continuous.

Is it possible to describe the solution to the linear ODE

$$\dot y_t = A_t + B_t(y_t),$$

using the exponential of the integral $\int_0^tB_s\,ds$, like in the case $V = \mathbb R^d$?

Note: the case I'm interested in is the second variational equation of an ODE in $\mathbb R^d$, and there we have $V = \mathbb R^{d\times d\times d}$. In particular, $V$ is finite-dimensional. However, viewing this as a problem in $\mathbb R^{d^3}$ seems contrived and doesn't seem to help much with deriving an actual solution. Similarly, the case $V = \mathbb R^{d\times d}$ (linear matrix ODE) cannot really be understood by indentifying $V \cong \mathbb R^{d^2}$.